# Loading OpenStreetMap in PyQGIS projection issue

Tags: pyqgis, openstreetmap, qgis-plugins

I'm currently developing a small plugin for QGIS where the objective is to show various locations on a map. For the users convenience I want to load OSM after I have loaded all the locations into QGIS.

So far this is what i got.

```
    def load_osm(self):
        url_params = 'type=xyz&url=https://tile.openstreetmap.org/%7Bz%7D/%7Bx%7D/%7By%7D.png&zmax=19&zmin=0&crs=EPSG4326'
        osm_layer = QgsRasterLayer(url_params, 'OpenStreetMap', 'wms')

        if osm_layer.isValid():
            QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(osm_layer)
        else:
            QgsMessageLog.logMessage('The layer is not valid')
```

From the code above this is the result.

[image]

What I want to achieve.
[image]

As you can see loading the OSM like I'm currently doing in the code, is messing up the zone and is not zooming. In the 2nd picture I imported the locations first and then dragged and dropped the OSM layer from the Explorer in QGIS.

Comment: OpenStreetMap is not a WMS, so possibly that is your error

Comment: Your projection is probably wrong, looks like 4326 on 3857 background

Comment: Just for reference, I ran your code on a QGIS project which is using a GDA94 based coord system (EPSG:28350) and it worked perfectly. What is the coord system of your project and/or the source data in the project at the start?

Comment: @nr_aus Source data is in Long, Lat

Comment: @IanTurton The project it self is based in 4326, but is somehow overwritten by the OSM layer, i think?

Comment: OSM will always be 3857, so you need to make sure QGis knows your points are 4326 not 3857 so it will reproject them for you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all the help, managed to get it to work by defining the CRS of the map layer before adding the map layer like this.

```
file_to_qgis = "file:///{}{}{}?delimiter={}&xField={}&yField={}".\
            format(os.getcwd(), "/", file, ",", "stop_lon", "stop_lat")
        layer_stoppesteder = QgsVectorLayer(file_to_qgis, "vtfk-stoppesteder", "delimitedtext")
        crs = layer_stoppesteder.crs()
        crs.createFromId(4326)
        layer_stoppesteder.setCrs(crs)

""" 
Code to add the layer goes here. 
"""
```

For the zoom to work properly i defined the correct layer as the active layer and used the QTimer class to delay the zoom until the layers actually was loaded and shown on the canvas like this.

```
    def active_layer_changed(self):
        active_layer = QgsProject.instance().mapLayersByName('vtfk-stoppesteder')[0]
        iface.setActiveLayer(active_layer)

        timer = QTimer()
        timer.singleShot(2000, self.zoom_to_active_layer)

    def zoom_to_active_layer(self):
        iface.zoomToActiveLayer()
```